# Snowflake - script to infer data type for all table/view columns and cast data type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have tables/views with single data type (VARCHAR) in Snowflake but I want to create a script that can dynamically iterate over all the columns of a table/view to infer data type and cast data types to a (mostly) correct data type.

I wasn't able to find an example but the logic would look like below. I'm planning on running this from a worksheet as this will be a one time run.

Example Pseudo code

```
def infer_data_type(column):
    ...
    return data_type

def process(table_or_view):
    """
    return: selected table or view after casting data type
    """

    for column in table_or_view.columns:
        data_type = infer_data_type(column)
        cast_data_type(column, data_type)
    ...

    return table_or_view


process(EXAMPLE_TABLE_OR_VIEW)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi - you don't seem to have actually asked a question. Given this is not a code writing service, presumably you aren't expecting anyone to write a load of code for you - so what, precisely, is the issue you want help with?

Comment: @NickW thanks for the comment. I definitely don't expect anyone to write code for me. I was looking for an approach since I'm new to snowflake. Since I've discovered and familiarize myself with stored procedures instead of having to use sql, I can script it.